# Displaying Message box values in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Am new to VBA. So posting this question:

**Requirement:** I want to display my message box values in a cell.

**For example:** 
[image]

Below is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    MsgBox "value of a cell is" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

When i click on the button it is displaying values for the cell A1 as below

[image]

But i want the values from the message box to display on any cell.

Lets say i want "value of a cell is 45" to be displayed on some other cell.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
MsgBox "value of a cell is" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

use

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1") = "value of a cell is " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Change `Cell E1` to your desired cell.

Comment: Thanks Mrig for your answer. But here you are hard coding  "value of a cell is" but i want it to be dynamic. I want the entire string from message box to be pulled up and to be placed in the cell

Comment: @NaveenVM - `to be placed in the cell`, in which cell you want result to be displayed?

Comment: I want to place the value from message box in cell B3 on the same work sheet.

Comment: @NaveenVM - What exactly do you mean by `"value of a cell is" but i want it to be dynamic`?

Comment: i mean to say ......Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1") = "value of a cell is " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")....here you are hard coding "value of a cell is" but i don't want that hard coding.....instead i want the entire string from the message box to be picked it up and place in a cell

Comment: @NaveenVM - That's what solution is doing. Just change `E1` to `B3` as you said `I want to place the value from message box in cell B3`

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with @Mrig
You tell a msgbox what to display just like you tell a cell what to display.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, s As String, x As String
    Set rng = Range("A1")
    s = "value of a cell is "
    x = s & rng.Value

    MsgBox x
    Range("B3") = x
End Sub
```